# MySQL8.0 User Configuration File

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I installed new MYSQL8.0 on my development server, and customize my.ini. After user creation, i realise new user not able to run the configuration file as admin, and it point to old version mysql5.5 my.ini. But i never install any mysql on this server, may i know how can i solve it, so all new user configuration will point to the right file.[image]

Appreciate that, if you could advise me. thank you

Answer (score 1):

In Windows - MySQL is usually installed in 
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL 8.0 Server\

Updating the below files (located in %APPDATA%\MySQL) with correct path might fix the issue

- .mylogin.cnf
- mysqld-auto.cnf

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html

Comment: yes, i already have this my.ini to customize, but only apply for admin, other user having this error.